# Docker pull fails for some layers from self-hosted Registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have encountered an issue with a self-hosted [Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/). When pulling a certain image, the pull fails for some of its layers. As soon as I start the `docker pull` command, some layers report:

```
9894d615bbeb: Retrying in 5 seconds
dfc282427f6f: Retrying in 5 seconds
8dbb865cf7b1: Retrying in 1 second
```

This happens immediately when the command is started, the layers are not large.

- The registry has been working flawlessly for about a year.
- Recently we adopted a more docker-centric CI/CD flow and the need to continuously clear up the registry arose. For that reason we run a nightly cleanup job of the registry:

  - Delete all manifests on the filesystem (except for a few persistent images we want to keep)
  - Run the `bin/registry garbage-collect` command to delete all non-referenced blobs
- I have verified that blobs for these failing layers do indeed exist on the registry, I can navigate to them on the filesystem.
- The issue reproduces both on local system and on a remote server
- The docker registry logs show that the HTTP request for the blob was successful:

  ```
  time="2019-05-03T13:09:21.714123801Z" level=info msg="response completed" go.version=go1.7.6 http.request.host=registry.example.com http.request.id=e5c01bee-a755-48a5-b87a-716560dd0e25 http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr=94.237.28.78 http.request.uri="/v2/applications/foo/dist-staging/blobs/sha256:9894d615bbebb5b235bb5a7aed17e9b2ba35c95c9fc8c0c763476c057536842f" http.request.useragent="docker/17.05.0-ce go/go1.7.5 git-commit/89658be kernel/4.4.0-145-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Swipely/Docker-API 1.33.6)" http.response.contenttype="application/octet-stream" http.response.duration=8.154072ms http.response.status=200 http.response.written=0 instance.id=92dfad5e-bf76-4db6-a8de-07901539d36e service=registry version=v2.6.2
  172.17.0.1 - - [03/May/2019:13:09:21 +0000] "GET /v2/applications/foo/dist-staging/blobs/sha256:9894d615bbebb5b235bb5a7aed17e9b2ba35c95c9fc8c0c763476c057536842f HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "" "docker/17.05.0-ce go/go1.7.5 git-commit/89658be kernel/4.4.0-145-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Swipely/Docker-API 1.33.6)"
  ```
- The docker registry is behind an nginx proxy, but its settings have not been changed recently. While debugging, I tried the following, with no luck:

  ```
  proxy_buffering off;
  proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
  ```

Is there anything else I should check? Can this be caused by the registry cleanup somehow? Why? How?

---

**Edit**

It seems that something was stale in the Registry cache, because restarting it started throwing `unknown blob` errors.

After rebuilding and re-pushing the image, this error went away and the Registry was able to serve the image to clients again.

I think that means that something got messed up during the registry cleanup, but why? `garbage-collect` should only remove non-referenced blobs and should be safe to use, if I understand it correctly?

---

This question took a turn but I will leave it here in its entirety for others.

Comment: We installed a local registry cache and we are also periodically experiencing the same issues.
A restart of Docker fixes them but it's a less than ideal solution.